# Yii2: Unable to auto login User

Tags: php, yii2, autologin

I am trying to auto login the user after saving the user information in the sign up process (I am not using the Yii2 `site/signup` action). After saving the user info, I am trying to auto login the user like this:

```
$model = new User;
$model->username = $user->username;
$model->password = $password;
if (\Yii::$app->user->login($model)) {
    return $this->redirect(['user/dashboard']);
}
```

It does not log the user in. What I am doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: Are you sure that your User model `implements IdentityInterface` ?

Comment: @gmc that's what exactly the issue was, thanks for help!